# Unable to boot with Windows 2008 DVD / USB Key

Tags: windows-server-2008, sas

I am trying to install Windows 2008 server on a HP Proliant DL180 G5. There is no built-in DVD reader so I need to use my LaCie USB one.

When I put the CD in and boot from the USB DVD on the server, I get the error message:

Boot Failed! Please insert boot media in selected boot device.

So I tried with another Windows bootable CD and still no luck.

What I've done then, I copied the installation DVD on my 16go USB key. Again, impossible to boot from the USB Key.

I have 2 147go SAS 15k HDD on my server. They are not showing in the Bios. I was wondering if this is a reason why nothing will boot on it.

I am trying to find a way to deploy Windows 2008 server on my HP server as soon as possible.

If you guys have ideas, feel free to let me know :)

Best regards,
David.

System Information:
HP Proliant DL180 G5
Quad-Core 2.5
4GO Ram 
2x 147GO SAS 15k

P.S. This is my first installation ever on SAS/SCSI HDD.

Thanks a bunch!

Edit:

Well, my bad! I purchased a new USB DVD and now I can install Windows 2008 server.

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect Mr. Denny's nailed it.

Also look for a bootup message about a boot menu (F12 is popular) to see if you can pop up a menu of available boot devices.

Not trying to be a jerk, but did you boot another computer from that DVD or USB to make sure it's happy?  I only say this because I've spun my wheels in this manner a few times.  ;)

Comment: When I insert the CD key in my laptop, a normal Windows XP SP3, the install prompt me to run the Install.exe or something so yes, it seems to work fine but I can install it from scratch on my server. I'm wondering if the SAS HDD are the problem. I don't see any SCSI/SAS controller in the BIOS and no HDD are found in there also.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to go into the BIOS and enable it to boot off the USB drive.

Comment: This has been done already. I can see the USB drive but unfortunately the NTFS format doesn't seems to be taken in consideration there... So Windows 2008 won't boot

Answer (score 1):

Have you made your USB key bootable?  I usually use [mkbt](http://www.nu2.nu/mkbt/).  You'll also need to ensure the BIOS is set to allow boot from USB

Comment: Yes it's supposed to be bootabled but I'll give a try to mkbt. Keep you posted!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the USB key bootable first.

You can do this by following these steps:
--please note that this process will format the USB key
1. Open a command prompt (an administrator command prompt if using Vista/Win7/Server 2008)
2. enter diskpart by typing in the following command: diskpart
3. find out which disk is the USB key by entering: list disk
4. note the disk number of the USB key (we'll use [diskNumber] as a placeholder in the next step)
5. select disk [diskNumber]
6. clean
7. create partition primary
8. select partition 1
9. active
10. format fs=fat32
11. assign
12. exit

Copy the files from the installation media to the USB key and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried it also but the USB key was considered as a volume instead as a Disk...

Answer (score 0):

When you boot from the USB drive does it say **no boot media**. What software are you using to create the DVD image installed on the USB drive ?.

This might help

1. Set BIOS to boot from removable
   media *ie: USB drive.*
2. Create an ISO of the DVD/CD with a
   tool like [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) using the
   **Read Disc** feature.
3. Reformat the USB drive, better be
   safe than sorry.
4. Then use a tool like [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to
   install the ISO image you created
   with InfraRecoder on the USB key.
   And reboot.

Comment: I used HP Tool to create the bootable so it started MS-DOS 98 but the setup (W2008) doesn't run on DOS...

I performed a NTFS format on the USB to make sure NTFS file were copied onto it but no luck again.